# Javascript value in closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I really can't explain myself why I failed in creating a closure and I get `undefined` in the code below:

```
function A() {
 this.p1=1;
 this.p2=2;
 this.f1=function(){
    alert(this.p1);
 }
 this.f2=function(){
    alert(this.p2);
    }
 this.action=function(param){
    if (param=='1')
        return this.f1;//by case
    else if (param=='2')
        return this.f2;
    };
}

var v=new A();
v.action("1")();
```

Comment: Why is this extra `()` in your last line? `v.action("1")();`

Comment: Because .action("1") returns a function

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I think it is because `this.f1` refers to the variable this.p1 before "this" is really a thing object). Besides, it's not much of a closure if you stick the closure variable in the object itself. If you drop the `this`. part of p1 and p2 (including in f1 and f2), it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're not 100% sure on what a closure is... Starting with your code:

```
function A()
{
    this.p1=1;//public
    var p2=2;//private
    this.f1=function()
    {
        alert(this.p1);
    };
    this.f2=function()
    {
        alert(p2);
    };
```

Here, I've defined `p2` as a variable, local to the constructor's scope, yet the public method `f2` *can* sitl access its value, change it even. That's a closure: code/data contained within its own specific scope. What you're doing with the following code:

```
    this.action=function(param)
    {
        if (param=='1')
        {
            return this.f1;
        }
        return this.f2;
    };
}
var v=new A();
v.action("1")();
```

Has little or nothing to do with a closure, you're returning a reference to a function (that happens to be an object method in this specific case). Why, then doesn't this `point` to the object it came from? Simple:

```
var foo = {name:'someObject'};
foo.retVal = v.action('1');//returns function
//much later:
foo.retVal();
```

Would you expect `this` to point to `v`, still? And wouldn't that be hellish to debug? upon calling a function (method or not), `this` will be the pointer of the context-object in which the function is called. Once `v.action('1')` returns, in your example, the function is returned to the global object, hence this will point to `this` or `window`

Comment: I'm really messed up with the difference between this.p1 and var p1 in your example..

Comment: So can one achieve a closure with this.p1? or it makes no sense

Comment: `this.p1`, assigns a property, `p1` to the object returned by constructor `A`. so if `var v = new A();` `v.p1` will be equal to whatever value you've assigned to `this.p1`. `var p1` creates a variable, not a property, so when using `var p1` instead of `this.p1`: `var v = new A();` => `v.p1 === undefined`. it's a hidden/enclosed (hence closure) piece of the object

Comment: Nope, you can't really make `this.p1`, because it'll be public (like all properties in JS. What you can do is `this.p1 = 'someVal'; var p1 = this.p1; this.resetP1(){ this.p1 = p1;};` This sets a variable (notice the exact same name as the property) to the same value _when the object is constructed_, you can then use the `resetP1` method (after having changed the `p1` property as much as you want, and it'll be reset to the value it was assigned when the object was instanciated. That would be considered a closure of sorts

Answer (score 4):

That has nothing to do with a closure.

You are returning a function reference from the method, and when you call it you expect it to be executed as a method in the object, but it's executed as a function with the global scope as context.

Use the [`call` method](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the function in the context of the object:

```
v.action("1").call(v);
```

Comment: I know that I can pass the context with the call function but I don't understand why the context is lost

Comment: Isn't it like a chain? action is called in v context and returns a function that is called then?

Comment: @radask the context is *always* lost when a function returns. That is, the value of `this` is determined by the circumstances of each function call, independent of any value(s) of `this` on previous or subsequent function calls.

Comment: @radashk: A method is only called as a method when the call is done using the object, e.g. `v.method();`. If you call a method without using the object directly, it's called with the global scope as context, e.g. `var f = v.method; f();`. The same happens when you return the function, the value of the expression `v.action("1")` is a function reference, and when you call it it's not called using the object.

Answer (score 1):

The functions are not binded to a specific this, that is to say:

```
(function() { console.log(this) })(); // Window
```

You can either use the call method, or (better) use the .bind method (make sure to polyfill for older browsers):

```
function A() {
 this.p1 = 1;
 this.p2 = 2;
}
A.prototype.f1 = function() {alert(this.p1)};
A.prototype.f2 = function() {alert(this.p2)};
A.prototype.action = function(param) {
  if ('1' == param) {
    return this.f1.bind(this);
  } else if (param == '2') {
    return this.f2.bind(this);
  }
};

var v = new A();
v.action("1")(); // 1
```

The bind method returns a new function which calls the original function with this set to the bind's argument. [Function.prototype.bind documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

`v.action("1")` is roughly the same as `action.call(v, "1")`

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a closure like this, "this" actually refers to the Window when it is called later. In order to avoid this, you need to assign "this" to another variable, like "that":

```
function A() {
var that = this;
 that.p1=1;
 that.p2=2;
 that.f1=function(){
    alert(that.p1);
 }
 that.f2=function(){
    alert(that.p2);
    }
 that.action=function(param){
    if (param=='1')
        return that.f1;//by case
    else if (param=='2')
        return that.f2;
    };
}

var v=new A();
v.action("1")();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your nested function `this` has another meaning.
Try using variable to pass reference inside, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VyyG/).

Answer (score 0):

As you intended

```
v.action("1")
```

returns the function defined as

```
function(){
    alert(this.p1);
}
```

You can also call it by adding a pair of brackets, like you did. However the `this` in that function will be bound to the global object (in browser it is `window`). And `window.p1` is `undefined`. That's what you get as output.

As mentioned already, you can decide what should be `this` in the function by calling it using `call` instead of the brackets:

```
v.action("1").call(v);
```

What `this` means in JavaScript is quite confusing. An explanation that helped me understand can be found in section *3.3 **The meaning of this (the egregious disaster)*** of [Javascript in Ten Minutes](https://github.com/spencertipping/js-in-ten-minutes/blob/master/js-in-ten-minutes.pdf?raw=true) (a worthwhile read though the whole document takes a lot more than ten minutes).